# How to use the Comparator interface

Tags: java, interface, sorting, comparator

I'm new to java, and I'm not really getting how to use the comparator interface.
I have an `ArrayList` of `Item`s in an `Inventory` class and an `Item` class.
In the `Item` class I wrote:

```
public class Item implements Comparator<Item> {
    //stuff
    ...
    @Override
    public int compare(Item a, Item b) {
        if (a.getID().compareToIgnoreCase(b.getID())>0)
            return 1;
        else if (a.getID().compareToIgnoreCase(b.getID())<0)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

The getID() method just gives the id, which I have to use to alphabetize the items.
I'm not sure if this is right, it made me put the `@Override` annotation, I'm not sure why. Also I wrote an interface that just says:

```
 public interface Comparator<Item>
{
    int compare(Item a, Item b);
}
```

I'm not sure about that bit. Also how do I implement this method to sort the arraylist created in the inventory class?

Thanks, if my question doesn't make sense or needs clarification just let me know.

Comment: Wait, Your `Item` class implements `Comparator`, which on its definition requires a generic `Item` to work. It seems you don't need a generic interface here...

Comment: What do you mean by generic interface?

Comment: I don't know how to explain... https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=generics+in+java

Comment: @bassandguitar, dude check my updated answer. I think that is what you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To use the [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface you have to implement it and pass it as an anonymous class to [Collections.sort(List list, Comparator c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) as the second parameter.

If you want to pass only the list to [Collections.sort(List list)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) then your `Item` class has to the implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

So in both cases the `Collections.sort` methods know how to order the elements in your list

here is some sample code:

Item class implementing `Comparable` + Inventory holding a list of items

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {

    String id = null;

    public Item(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item o) {
        return - id.compareToIgnoreCase(o.id);
    }
}


public class Inventory {

    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addItem(Item item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
        inventory.addItem(new Item("2"));
        inventory.addItem(new Item("4"));
        inventory.addItem(new Item("1"));
        inventory.addItem(new Item("7"));

        Collections.sort(inventory.items, new Comparator<Item>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
                return o1.id.compareToIgnoreCase(o2.id);
            }
        });
        System.out.println(inventory.items);

        Collections.sort(inventory.items);
        System.out.println(inventory.items);

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 4, 7] // ascending
[7, 4, 2, 1] // descending since the compareTo method inverts the sign of the comparison result.
```

Answer (score 16):

**EDIT:** First of all, a couple of things:

1. The `@Override` annotation should not be mandatory. If Eclipse wants you to put it on, don't worry.
2. ***Don't write your own Comparator interface. Delete that definition NAO and use the one provided by Java.*** Reinventing the wheel probably violates the Unspoken Code of Computer Programming in about 15 different ways. Use `import java.util.Comparator;` at the very top of your code (before the `public class` stuff) to a) use the version given by Java and b) make your code compatible with pretty much everything else that exists in the world.

---

The Comparator interface is not used to create a class that can put itself in order. This is the Comparable interface.

Both are similar, so I will describe both here.

## java.util.Comparator

The Comparator interface, as you already know, has one method: `compare`. Comparator is generic (uses the angle brackets `<>`) and takes the type it will compare inside the `<>`. The thing is that Comparators are used to compare items of *other classes*. For example, I could create a Comparator for `java.lang.Integers` that returns the opposite of the "natural order" (how Integers are usually ordered).

Comparators are used mostly to give other objects a way to sort their parameters when they are not in natural order. For example, the [`java.util.TreeSet` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) takes a Comparator for its sorting capability.

## java.lang.Comparable

Comparable's purpose is to say that an object can be compared. It is also generic and takes the type that it can be compared to. For example, a `Comparable<String>` can be compared to Strings.

Comparable has one method: `compareTo()`. Unlike Comparator's `compare()`, `compareTo` takes one parameter. It works like `compare`, except it uses the invoking object as one parameter. So, `comparableA.compareTo(comparableB)` is the same as `comparator.compare(comparableA, comparableB)`.

Comparable mostly establishes the natural order for objects, and is the default way to compare objects. Comparator's role is to override this natural order when one has different needs for data comparison or sorting.

## ArrayList Sorting

To sort a `List`, you could use the method already available: scroll down to `sort` on the [`java.util.Collections` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html). One method takes a Comparator, the other does not. `sort` is static; use `Collections.sort(...)`, not `Collections c = new Collections(); c.sort(...)`. (`Collections` doesn't even have a constructor anyway, so *meh*.)

Comment: Java 8 Comparator does have a few more methods, as listed [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/Comparator-interface-in-collection-framework) for example, which makes is much much more comfortable to use it. This just saved me some bitter work so I thought it could be useful to mention it. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing up the interfaces `Comparator` and `Comparable`.

Comparator: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comparable: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

The purpose of Comparator is a class (declared anonymously on the spot or otherwise) that can be passed to an operation that needs an ordering, and it defines the sort that will be used on the item. **Comparator is to be used OUTSIDE of the class that needs sorting, if there is an alternative way you want to sort it by.**

The purpose of Comparable is to say that the class (that implements Comparable) has a natural ordering - and this is what it is. **If your class that needs sorting has a natural ordering, then define it as Comparable.** (A class that implements Comparable's sort order can still be overriden by a Comparator. On the other hand, if the class is not Comparable than also passing a Comparator is mandatory for ordering to be possible.)

Comment: All I know is I have to use implements Comparator on the item class, how do I then use comparable for the inventory class?

Comment: @bassandguitar You are wrong - `Item` would implement `Comparable`, OR `Inventory` would accept a `Comparator` which it would use for sorting its `Item`s.

Comment: how would I use the compareTo() method to sort the array in the inventory class?

Comment: @bassandguitar Operations that permit sorting check to see if the class of the objects they are sorting implements Comparable. If it does, it uses the class's compareTo() definition.

Answer (score 0):

You've implemented the wrong interface, you want [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Comment: Please indicate how `Comparable` is used.

Answer (score 0):

Use of *@Override* annotation is a standard practice in editors like eclipse, netbeans to notify developer that he is overriding/implementing parent class/interface method. It is optional.

Don't implement this interface in your Item class. Create a *new* class and implement the `Comparator` interface.

```
public class ItemCompare implements Comparator<Item> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Item a, Item b) {
        if (a.getID().compareToIgnoreCase(b.getID())>0)
            return 1;
        else if (a.getID().compareToIgnoreCase(b.getID())<0)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And then, in your main class, do this:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList<Item>

Collections.sort(al, new ItemCompare())
```

Comment: You are wrong, both Comparator and Comparable are interfaces. The rest of your answer is ok.

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out. Silly me. Something got mixed up.

Comment: I think I understand, the assignment says to use the compareTo() method though I just saw, how would I use this instead? and so ItemCompare needs to be its own class?

Comment: @bassandguitar If the assignment says to use compareTo(), compareTo() is the method of Comparable, not Comparator. So, implement Comparable for Item and go from there.

Comment: You made two changes when you should have either changed the interface or the class that implements it. `ItemCompare` can implement `Comparator` or `Item` can implement `Comparable`.

Comment: @MathSquared11235, Yes math you are right. You can do either. But I generally like creating a new class and then implement Comparator. Because this practice will be helpful when you are creating more than 1 Comparators. Complete Separation from main class which also helps manage multiple Comparators with ease and increases clarity

Comment: @RaviTrivedi I see what you're saying. I was simply pointing out that you were using the `Comparable` interface as `Comparator` is used. I edited your post to fix it, but it hasn't been reviewed yet. **EDIT:** It has.

Comment: +1 to both MathSquared11235 and patashu for pointing out mistakes.

Comment: The assignment says to implement it in the item class though