# How to make the comparison the responsibility of an object that's passed to the sorting routine by strategy pattern?

Tags: sorting, oop, design-patterns, programming-languages, gang-of-four

I started self learning design patterns from Design Patterns by Gang of Four

> Parameterized types give us a third way (in addition to class
>   inheritance and  object composition)  to compose behavior  in
>   object-oriented  systems. Many designs can be implemented using any of
>   these three techniques. **To parameterize a sorting routine by the
>   operation it uses to compare elements**, we could make the comparison
>
> 1. an  operation  implemented  by  subclasses  (an  application  of  Template Method (325)),
> 2. **the responsibility of an object that's passed to the sorting routine (Strategy (315))**, or
> 3. an argument  of a C++ template or Ada generic that specifies the name of the function to call to compare the elements.

I looked up the strategy pattern, but was still wondering how the second way "make the comparison  the responsibility of an object that's passed to the sorting routine (Strategy)" is done?

I'd appreciate some example(s) in whichever OO language: C++, C#, Java, Python, ...

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126563/how-to-use-the-comparator-interface .  Imagine you have a class Person, that implements compareTo based on surname.  That's great, but occasionally you might want to sort on Age, or Salary, or ...    That's when you'd create a Comparator that you pass to the sorting routine.

Comment: @racraman thanks. What design patterns are comparator and comparable implemented based on?